# How to use ActiveRecord in module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```rb
require 'active_record'

module Module1
    module Module2
        class Database
            ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
                :adapter  => 'postgresql',
                :host     => 'db_url',
                :username => 'db_username',
                :password => 'db_password',
                :database => 'db_name'
            )


            class People < ActiveRecord::Base
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I can move the ActiveRecord establish connection bit into a an initialize function, and instantiate the class however, I still get a `NoMethod` error when I try to call the People class.

The goal is to use it outside of the module/class by doing something like the following:

```rb
db = Module1::Module2::Database
db.People.all.each do |Person|
  puts Person
end
```

Comment: This isn't something you actually need nor will this  work as intended. ActiveRecord has built in [connection switching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html). Models can also connect through the `connect` class method. To access nested constants you need to use `::` not `.` but its not nested in an instance of the class. Maybe just start with some tutorials on ActiveRecord and learn how to tool is supposed to be used? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: I'm connecting to around 10 different clusters with 50 databases each that are all complete unrelated to each other but have similar structures. Don't think switching between reader/writer automatically would be much benefit for me, I'd rather just open a new connection as desired

Comment: Yeah I cant see how this will actually help in any way with that requirement. You're just opening a connection when the module is first evaluated - and the class nested inside won't even use that connection without further configuration. I get that this is an idea you're entrenched on but it really doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: Is there any reason I can't just create an array of db objects with that module ? I don't really understand what your concern is 

I was going to have 

db1 = Module1::Module2::Database
db2 = Module1::Module2::Database

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to move into another module so it doesn't require instantiation, and it's not in a class:

```rb
require 'active_record'

module Module1
    module Module2
        module Database
            ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
            class People < ActiveRecord::Base
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Then to use it:

```rb
# get a configuration object like this similiar to how rails is configured
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yaml'))
db.establish_connection(dbconfig["database1"])
db = Module1::Module2::Database::People
db.all.each do |x|
    puts x.created_at
end

# switch between profiles
db.establish_connection(dbconfig["database2"])
db = Module1::Module2::Database::People
db.all.each do |x|
    puts x.created_at
end
```

`config/database.yaml` should resemble this:

```yaml
database1:
  adapter: <adapter_name>
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  host: <host>
  database: <database_name>
```

This approach is "single threaded" in the sense that you can only be connected to one database at a time because ActiveRecord connections overwrite each other as you switch between them. So switch get your data and switch again.

Comment: Does this actually work with different modules connecting to different databases correctly? I am 95% sure that your modules will overwrite one another's connections.

Comment: It works if concurrency isn't a requirement :) - would be nice if that were doable but I wasn't able to find a way to do it so that they'd create completely new contexts without specifying new modules - but I felt that wasn't a great solution since I don't know the amount of clusters/databases I'll be connecting to. 

Since it's only a few hundred databases and relatively simple queries in my case, this single threaded approach works fine however I'd love to know how to do this dynamically.